# How can I solve file upload issue?

Tags: google-colaboratory, yolo, yolov4

[![I cannot upload the obj.names and obj.data files][1]][1]

[image: Even though my path file is correct, I am not able to upload obj.names and obj.data files.]

Even though my path file is correct, I am not able to upload obj.names and obj.data files.
I tried as /mydrive/yolov4/obj.names.gdoc ./data --> it did not work either

Comment: I think it is because of the names of your files. Try with /my/drive/yolov4/obj.names.gdoc . If not, just press tab to autocomplete the root of such files.